# SVD "High Accurancy" Demmel - Kahan Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm trying to write the SVD algorithm from Demmel - Kahan ("Computing Accurate Singular Value Decomposition") in MATLAB.

I wrote almost all the code but i don't understand some steps of this algorithm.

The step where the algorithm says "Handle specially, Compute SVD of the 2x2 submatrix from iLower to iUpper+1"...do i have to apply the zero-shift QR diagonalization to the 2x2 submatrix?

Then when it says that I have to apply the standard shifted algorithm it doesn't explain how to do it just using the diagonal and upper diagonal vectors from the bidiagonal matrix.

However, I don't think that the problem is only in these steps because sometimes my code works and the result is just like that from the svd() built-in function in matlab.

I'll link the article with the algorithm from Demmel - Kahan and the code that I wrote here, maybe someone can help me.

Thanks!
[Demmel - Kahan High Accurancy Singular Value Decomposition](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn03.pdf)

```
dir=0;
eps = 1e-010; 
tol = 100*eps; 
maxit = 3*(n^2); 
fudge=min(m,n); 
s=diag(B);
e=diag(B,1);
lambda=abs(s);

for j=n-1:-1:1
    lambdas(j)=abs(s(j))*(lambda(j+1)/(lambda(j+1)+abs(e(j))));
end
mu(1)=abs(s(1));
for j = 1:n-1
    mu(j+1) = abs(s(j+1))*(mu(j)/(mu(j)+abs(e(j))));
end
lambdaMin=min(lambdas);
muMin=min(mu);
sigmaLower = min(lambdaMin,muMin);
s1=max(abs(s));
e1=max(abs(e));
sigmaUpper = max(s1,e1);
thresh = max((tol*sigmaLower),(maxit*realmin));
for iter=1:maxit
    for i=1:n-1
        if abs(e(i))<=thresh
            iUpper=i;
        else iUpper=n;
        end
    end
    if iUpper==1    
        break;
    end

    for i=n-1:-1:1
        if abs(e(i))<=thresh
            iPrime=i;
        else iPrime=0;
        end
    end
    iLower=iPrime+1;
        tmp=B(iLower:iUpper,iLower:iUpper);
    if iUpper==iLower+1
                [s,e]=ZeroShiftQR(s,e,iLower,iUpper,1);
                e(iLower)=0;
        B(iLower:iUpper,iLower:iUpper)=diag(s)+diag(e,1);
        continue;
    end
        if B(iLower:iUpper,iLower:iUpper)~=tmp
        s=diag(B);
        e=diag(B,1);
        if abs(s(iLower))<=abs(s(iUpper))
            dir=1;
        else dir=2;
        end
    end
% Convergence criteria
if dir==1 % Convergence criteria 1b,1a,2a
    if abs(e(iUpper-1)/lambdas(iUpper))<=tol % 1b to e(iUpper-1)
        e(iUpper-1)=0;
    end
    for j=1:n-1 % Criteria 1a
        if abs(e(j)/mu(j))<=tol
            e(j)=0;
        end
    end
    % Criteria 2a to e(iUpper-1)
    tmp=mu(1)/sqrt(n-1);
    for i=2:n-1
        if mu(i)/sqrt(n-1)<tmp
            tmp=mu(i)/sqrt(n-1);
        end
    end
    if e(iUpper-1)*e(iUpper-1)<=0.5*tol*(tmp*tmp-abs(s(iUpper))*abs(s(iUpper)))
        e(iUpper-1)=0;
    end
else % Convergence criteria 1a,1b,2b
    if abs(e(iLower)/mu(iLower))<=tol % Criteria 1a to e(iLower)
        e(iLower)=0;
    end
    for j=n-1:-1:1 % Criteria 1b
        if abs(e(j)/lambdas(j))<=tol
            e(j)=0;
        end
    end
    % Criteria 2b 
    tmp=lambdas(2)/sqrt(n-1);
    for i=3:n-1
        if lambdas(i)/sqrt(n-1)<tmp
           tmp=lambdas(i)/sqrt(n-1);
        end
    end
    if e(iLower)*e(iLower)<=0.5*tol*(tmp*tmp-abs(s(iLower))*abs(s(iLower)))
        e(iLower)=0;
    end
end
% Compute the shift
if (fudge*tol*sigmaLower/sigmaUpper)<=eps
    shift=0;
else if dir==1
        w=s(iUpper);
        C=diag(s)+diag(e,1);
        C=C*C';
        C=C(end-1:end,end-1:end);
        [lambda_1,lambda_2] = eig2(C); % Calculate the eigenvalues of C
        if abs(C(2,2)-lambda_1)<abs(C(2,2)-lambda_2)
            shift=lambda_1;
        else shift=lambda_2;
        end
    else w=s(iLower);
         C=diag(s)+diag(e,1);
         C=C*C';
         C=C(1:2,1:2);
         [lambda_1,lambda_2] = eig2(C);
         if abs(C(2,2)-lambda_1)<abs(C(2,2)-lambda_2)
            shift=lambda_1;
         else shift=lambda_2;
         end
    end
    if (shift/w)^2<=eps
        shift=0;
    end
end
% QR iterations
if shift==0
    if dir==1
        [s,e]=ZeroShiftQR(s,e,iLower,iUpper,1); % Zero-shift QR iterations with direction down
        if e(iUpper-1)<=thresh
            e(iUpper-1)=0;
        end
    else [s,e]=ZeroShiftQR(s,e,iLower,iUpper,2); % Zero-shift QR iterations with direction up
        if e(iLower)<=thresh
            e(iLower)=0;
        end
    end
else if dir==1
        [s,e]=ZeroShiftQR(s,e,iLower,iUpper,1); % This is where it should be applied the shifted QR dir. down
        if e(iUpper-1)<=thresh
            e(iUpper-1)=0;
        end
    else  [s,e]=ZeroShiftQR(s,e,iLower,iUpper,2); % This is where it should be applied the shifted QR dir. up
        if e(iLower)<=thresh
            e(iLower)=0;
        end
    end
end     
end
% Sort singular values
s=sort(abs(s),'descend')
```